# Get all container registries under a subscription - .NET Azure sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-container-registry

Looking out for .NET SDK references to get a specified container registry or all the container registries in a resource group or the subscription.

Need references apart from the REST API available:
`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries?api-version=2019-05-01`

I have seen that the operation is available through Powershell and CLI cmdlet; `Get-AzContainerRegistry` and `az acr list`, but looking out for .NET SDK based library references (Azure.ResourceManager preferred) for the same.

I have gone through https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net, but there's no extension related to get a specific or list the container registries under a subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuget packages:

- [Azure.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity)
- [Azure.ResourceManager(beta)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager)

```cs
// Change these as needed
ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
Subscription subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

// You can also get the resource group first if you know it already
// subscription.GetResourceGroups().Get("myresourcegroup");
var registyResources = subscription.GetGenericResourcesAsync("resourceType eq 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries'").AsPages();

await foreach (var resource in registyResources)
{
    var id = resource.Values.First().Id;
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Resource Group: {id.ResourceGroupName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Container registry name: {id.Name}");
}
```

You can also explore the returned resource if you need any other information. You can then continue with the [specialized SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Containers.ContainerRegistry/) for the specific Container Registry.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That works. Do you have reference document for all other type of filters we can use in GetGenericResourcesAsync method?

Comment: @Prachi You can look for general information on ARM $filter operation. Some Examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.resources.subscription.getgenericresources?view=azure-dotnet-preview or here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/filter-syntax